# Node JS project getting: "command failed signal SIGTERM" error on deployment to digital ocean

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, deployment, digital-ocean

Out of 7 pods 4 of them are running and 3 are not and throwing the error

```
npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.4 -> 10.4.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.4.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.4.0` to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! path /app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! signal SIGTERM
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node dist/index.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!
```

For reference this is our .yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gateway-consumer-node
  labels:
    app: gateway-consumer-node
  annotations:
    externalTrafficPolicy: Local
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: gateway-consumer-node
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gateway-consumer-node
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gateway-consumer-node
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  replicas: 7
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 8
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gateway-consumer-node
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gateway-consumer-node
          image: <IMAGE>
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
          env:
```

and this is our package.json

```
{
    "name": "gateway-consumer-node",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Client gateway for all the services",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts",
        "start": "node dist/index.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "tsc -p .",
        "postbuild": "cp ./src/public/* ./dist/"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.137.0",
        "@farcaster/hub-nodejs": "^0.11.0",
        "@lighthouse-web3/sdk": "^0.2.8",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1183.0",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "bs58": "^5.0.0",
        "connect-timeout": "^1.9.0",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
        "cookie-session": "^2.0.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
        "elastic-apm-node": "^3.38.0",
        "ethers": "^5.5.1",
        "express": "^4.18.1",
        "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
        "express-fileupload": "^1.4.0",
        "express-validator": "^6.14.1",
        "googleapis": "^108.0.0",
        "ioredis": "^5.2.3",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
        "morgan": "^1.10.0",
        "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
        "multer-s3": "^3.0.1",
        "node-cron": "^3.0.2",
        "notion-types": "^6.13.4",
        "npm": "^8.13.1",
        "open-graph-scraper": "^5.0.5",
        "siwe": "^1.1.6",
        "socket.io": "^4.5.3",
        "stripe": "^14.14.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.8.2",
        "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
        "tweetnacl": "^1.0.3",
        "typescript": "^4.7.3",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2",
        "web3.storage": "^4.3.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/connect-timeout": "^0.0.36",
        "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
        "@types/cookie-session": "^2.0.44",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
        "@types/ejs": "^3.1.3",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
        "@types/express-fileupload": "^1.2.2",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8",
        "@types/morgan": "^1.9.3",
        "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
        "@types/multer-s3": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/node": "^18.7.14",
        "@types/node-cron": "^3.0.7",
        "@types/open-graph-scraper": "^4.8.1",
        "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4"
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out why this is happening and the same config runs on our dev cluster but fails for 3/7 pods in our production cluster.

[Terminal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtY6Q.jpg)

Tried restarting all the pods but this worked initially for around 20-25 minutes then. the 3 failed again.

Comment: Is something happening that would cause the application to not answer HTTP requests within 5 minutes?  Have you tried to instrument your application or startup more to see what might be happening?